# Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, nuget-package

i have installed the nuget package for asp.net webapi 2.2.
and now when i am executing this command

PM>  Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

from nuget package manager it is showing this error.

Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: If this is through Visual Studio can you try going through the graphical user interface instead of command-line?

Comment: @ankipatel , can you share version of Visual Studio and Framework?

Comment: how? can u explain it? please...

Comment: visual studio version 2013, framework 4.5

Comment: i have followed this link http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the package source in the PackageManagerConsole Window. Change it to nuget.org from the dropdown, to install the package from the online repository.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same issue . I have followed below steps and it works for me.

Before **Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors**. check the nuget.org link in package manager settings.

In Visual studio click Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager settings

verify by selecting a tree item

**NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources**

"**[https://www.nuget.org/api/v2**"](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2**%22) is added or not. If not then add this by given any name and source as this url. then try again to install WebApi.Cors

**Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Open visual studio as administrator.
2. Clear cache.
3. Install the package